# How to know that marker I press in osmdroid maps?

Tags: java, marker, osmdroid

I would like to know how I can control which marker I clicked on osmdroid.

```
List<Marker> markerList_OSM = new ArrayList<>();
```

...
...

```
                Marker coorLoad = new Marker(map);
                map.getOverlays().add(coorLoad);
                markerList_OSM.add(coorLoad);
```

Now, how can I control the press marker? both long and short press.

In the google maps I use:

```
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
        public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker markerSelect) {
......
......
......
return false;
        }
    });
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To control a long press, you have to subclass the Marker class, and implement onLongPress method:

```
@Override public boolean onLongPress(final MotionEvent event, final MapView mapView) {
        boolean touched = hitTest(event, mapView);
        if (touched){
           //here, do whatever you want
           //....
        }
        return touched;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [setOnMarkerClickListener](https://osmdroid.github.io/osmdroid/javadocs/osmdroid-android/release/index.html) on a Marker instance.

```
coorLoad.setOnMarkerClickListener(new Marker.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker, MapView mapView) {
        ....
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you very much. I have implemented setOnMarkerClickListener in each Marker and it works.

Comment: but, how can I control the long press?